# Workflow Foundation Modify Activity Implementation

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have a XAML file with windows workflow foundation code saved to file. I want to be able to:

- Read
- Modify
- Write

I've tried using XamlServices.Load to create both a DynamicActivity and an ActivityBuilder. Both of these have an implementation property, but I'm not sure how/if I can use that to traverse the tree of Activities.

Modifying the properties looks fairly easy but I need to modify that implementation details. Such as:

- Adding New activities
- Reading the parameters of existing activities
- Changing the parameters of existing activities
- Adding new child activities to existing activities

I'm wondering if I am barking up the wrong tree with XamlServices. There is also ActivityXamlServices and I have messed around with that also. Perhaps I should just parse straight Xml, because I don't actually need to execute the code, just modify it.

Edit: I've got a little closer. Using WorkflowInspectionServices, I can get the display names of all activities in the tree. But I can't see how to modify any of the arguments or connections.

Ok, I've made further progress. I can cast every activity returned by WorkflowInspectionServices.GetActivities to the necessary activity - but this means having to write code for every activity type I want to use. Isn't there some way to automatically generate a tree of corresponding objects?